# $\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that $\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right]$ converges when $0<s<1$.

Note that this series is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}$. It might seem counterintuitive that the series converges if $0<s<1$.

Comment: You can found this problem from A Course of Modern Analysis by Whittaker.

Comment: Yes that's the point : finding the analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$n^{-s}-\frac1{s-1} (n^{1-s}-(n+1)^{1-s})= n^{-s}-\int_n^{n+1} x^{-s}dx=\int_n^{n+1}\int_n^x st^{-s-1}dtdx$$

Comment: I am still not sure what kind of convergence test I should use to show the series converges when $0 < s < 1$.

Comment: The RHS is bounded by $|n^{-s-1}|$

Comment: That makes so much sense!

Answer (score 0):

Following on reuns' steps

\begin{aligned}
\int_n^{n+1}\Big(\int_n^x st^{-s-1}dt\Big)dx &=s\int_n^{n+1}\Big(\int^{n+1}_t t^{-s-1}dx\Big)dt= s\int^{n+1}_nt^{-s-1}(n+1-t)\,dt\\
&\leq s\int^{n+1}_n t^{-s-1}\,dt=n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}
\end{aligned}

Putting things together

$$ 0\leq n^{-s}-\frac1{s-1} (n^{1-s}-(n+1)^{1-s}) \leq s\int^{n+1}_n t^{-s-1}\,dt=n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s}
$$

since $0<s<1$. Then the result follows by comparison for $\sum_n(n^{-s}-(n+1)^{-s})$ is a convergent telescopic sum.