# Show $\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right] = \zeta(s)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, riemann-zeta

While playing with the Basel Problem, I derived this generalized Riemann Zeta $\zeta(s)$ formula

**Proposition**

$$\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right] = \zeta(s)$$

**Proof**

[image: basel]

Area below the curve is

$$\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^s} \, dx = \frac{1}{s-1}$$

Area above the curve for each rectangle is

$$\frac{1}{n^s} - \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{x^s} \, dx = \frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)$$

Total area above and below the curve is

$$\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right]$$

Rearranging the series

\begin{align*}
\small \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right] &= \overbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}}^{\text{Riemann Zeta}}+ \overbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)}^{\text{Telescoping}} \\
&= \zeta(s) + \frac{1}{1 - s}
\end{align*}

Therefore

$$\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right] = \frac{1}{s-1} + \zeta(s) + \frac{1}{1 - s}$$

resulting in the Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$

$$\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right]= \zeta(s)$$

$\blacksquare$

**Questions**

I'm curious if that's a valid proof? Also, searching for that formula, it was mentioned in these posts below but I couldn't find any reference to its derivation as they're more focused on proving convergence?

---

[$\frac{1}{s-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left(\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s-1}} - \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right)\right]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714558/frac1s-1-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac1ns-frac1s-1-left-frac1)

---

[convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{1}{s-1}\left\{\frac{1}{{(n+1)}^{s-1}}-\frac{1}{n^{s-1}}\right\}\right]$ (new methods)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782200/convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-left-frac1ns-frac1s-1-left-frac?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I don't think that Wolfram Alpha counts as a proof. On the other hand, once the convergence is proven, the result is quite trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could rewrite the sum as (provided the sum converges): $$\frac1{s-1}+\zeta(s)+\frac1{s-1}(\zeta(s-1)-1-\zeta(s-1))$$Simplifying we get the desired claim. Your proof is correct but it is overkill.

Comment: Thanks. [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2Fn%5Es+%2B+1%2F%28s-1%29+%28%281%2F%28n%2B1%29%5E%28s-1%29%29+-+%281%2Fn%5E%28s-1%29%29%29%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+Infinity%7D%5D) confirms it too. Are there other references on how that formula was derived, perhaps using a different approach?

Comment: Technically you could try proving it using the Euler Maclaurin Summation formula or the Abel Plana formula, but as I said for your method, any other method is overkill.